# If $A^{pq}_r$ and $B^{pq}_r$ are tensors, prove that their sum and difference are also tensors of the same rank

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

> If $A^{pq}_r$ and $B^{pq}_r$ are tensors, prove that their sum and difference are also tensors of the same rank

Proof: By hypothesis $A_{r}^{\rho q}$ and $B_{r}^{p q}$ are tensors, so that we have
$$
\bar{A}_{k}^{i j}=\frac{\partial \bar{x}^{i}}{\partial x^{p}} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^{j}}{\partial x^{q}} \frac{\partial x^{\gamma}}{\partial \bar{x}^{k}} A_{r}^{p}
$$
$$\bar{B}^{i j}_k=\frac{\partial \bar{x}^{i}}{\partial x^{\rho}} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^{j}}{\partial x^{q}} \frac{\partial x^{r}}{\partial \bar{x}^{k}} B_{r}^{\rho q}$$
By Adding (1) and (2), we have
$$\bar{A}_{k}^{i j}+\bar{B}_{k}^{i j}=\frac{\partial \bar{x}^{i}}{\partial x^{p}} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^{j}}{\partial x^{q}} \frac{\partial x^{r}}{\partial \bar{x}^{k}}\color{red}{\left(A_{p}^{p q}+B_{r}^{p q}\right)}$$
Thus, $A_{r}^{p q}+B_{r}^{p q}$ is a tensor of the same rank and type as $A_{r}^{p q}$ and $B_{r}^{p q}$

Again, by subtracting (1) and (2), we also have
$$
\bar{A}_{k}^{i j}- \bar{B}_{k}^{i j}=\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial x^{p}} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^{j}}{\partial x^{q}} \frac{\partial x^{r}}{\partial \bar{x}^{K}}\color{red}{\left(A_{p}^{p q}-B_{r}^{p q}\right)}
$$
Thus, $A_{r}^{p q}-B_{r}^{p q}$ is a tensor of the same rank and type as $A_{p}^{p q}$ and $B_{p}^{p q}$.

---

$(1)$ I don't understand, what's the point of this proof? As we want to prove what is $\color{red}{\left(A_{p}^{p q}+B_{r}^{p q}\right)}$, and use this inside the proof.

$(2)$ Why we need to bring another coordinate as we used transformation of coordinate here?

I'm really struggling to understand these basic theorem/statement related to tensor. It will be a great help if you suggest me some good resource before I start learning tensor calculus. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are probably reading a book that defines a tensor using transformation properties.  Look up your definition of a tensor. Then prove that if A and B transform like tensors, then so does C=(A+B)

Comment: The sad part is, the lecturer didn't suggest any book. All I am doing is searching his unclear statement/proof from (his lecture note). After a lot of searching, I manage the book which he was following, named "Tensors and Their Applications by Nazrul Islam". And the interesting fact is, the book itself didn't clear the definition. @ContraKinta

Comment: @falamiw There are certainly better textbooks than that you have found. The problem is that these books will be not compatible with your lectures.